# How to change the folder where data goes in Docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, nextcloud

1. I have a Digitalocean server (debian 11) and I want to host my nextcloud there and also other apps.
2. For that, I choosed the docker nextcloud way (nginx + let's encrypt).
3. I noticed I was almost out of disk space. So I added a volume.
4. Now, I want all my nextcloud data goes there, in that volume.

   trying to do that i've already tried:

   - sudo mkdir /var/lib/docker/volumes/volume_nyc1_01
   - sudo vi /etc/docker/daemon.json

     ```
     {
       "graph": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/volume_nyc1_01"
     }
     ```
5. sudo docker-compose down and sudo docker-compose up -d
6. But when i run the command docker info, still get

`Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker`

I will really appreciate it any suggestion or help

Comment: Maybe share the `docker-compose.ymal` file ? that can helpful.

Comment: If you want to move data of your Nextcloud instance to other volume, you could try create a mapping: map `/var/www/html` in your Nextcloud container to `/var/lib/docker/volumes/volume_nyc1_01`. But still, as other mentioned, share your `docker-compose.yaml` file could be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This commands were missing

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl stop docker.socket
sudo systemctl stop container
```

after that I could see the root directory has changed